# How to Disable Ray in Python with a Mock module for Debugging and Profiling

Tags: python, ray

I am working on a Python project that extensively uses asyncio and ray. In my code, I have several methods prefixed with async for asynchronous execution, and I also utilize the ray.remote decorator to parallelize certain classes. However, I now need to disable Ray temporarily to debug and profile my code effectively.

To achieve this, I plan to create a mock Ray class that can serve as a replacement for the original ray module. By using this mock class, I aim to seamlessly switch between the actual Ray implementation and the mock version without modifying the rest of the code. The idea is to use the same method implementations from the original classes, ensuring code reusability and easier maintenance.

Here's an example of the class I want to mock:

```py
@ray.remote
class A:
    def method1():
        return 3
```

And I currently use this class as follows:

```py
obj = A.remote()
result = await obj.method1.remote()
```

To proceed with my plan, I would like to create a RayMock class that can be utilized as a replacement for the original ray module. Here's how I envision using it:

```py
from ray_mock import RayMock
ray = RayMock()
```

By integrating this RayMock class into my codebase, I expect to retain the original functionality while being able to disable Ray for debugging and profiling purposes.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or code examples on how to implement the RayMock class and utilize it as described above. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd find this immensely valuable! Did you get to a working implementation?

Comment: @AshEldritch No, I failed after several trials. If you think this is immensely valuable,  upvoting the post would help. Maybe some others would help but I believe it should be comprehensively handled by Ray itself in one of their further updates.